# Flask + Celery + socketio RuntimeError: Working outside of request context

Tags: javascript, python, flask, celery

I am currently trying to design a flask app that allows real time charts through the use of sockets and celery. I want to be able to get data asynchronously and then send that via a socket to the client. I am however getting the error: `RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.` I get this when the socket first connects.

stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bev/.virtualenvs/flask_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bev/PycharmProjects/flask_project/celery_config.py", line 15, in __call__
    return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bev/.virtualenvs/flask_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bev/PycharmProjects/flask_project/main.py", line 20, in async_data
    send(jsonify({"result": sample(range(101), 6)}))
  File "/Users/bev/.virtualenvs/flask_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/json.py", line 251, in jsonify
    if current_app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] and not request.is_xhr:
  File "/Users/bev/.virtualenvs/flask_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/Users/bev/.virtualenvs/flask_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/Users/bev/.virtualenvs/flask_project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 37, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send
from random import sample
from celery_config import make_celery


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "thisisasecret"
socketio = SocketIO(app)

app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL="amqp://localhost//",
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND="rpc://"
)
celery = make_celery(app)


@celery.task(name="main.async_data")
def async_data():
    # for now this is very small as an example
    # preferably batched to be done every 15 minutes.
    send(jsonify({"result": sample(range(101), 6)}))
    return True


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("chart.html")


@socketio.on("connect")
def handle_connection():
    async_data.delay()
    print("You are connected and we are getting your data")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

celery_config.py

```
from celery import Celery


def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
                    broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

chart javascript

```
let chartConfig = {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "GOOG",
            data: [],
            borderColor: "rgba(22, 172, 65, 1)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            fill:false
        }]
    }
};

let socket = io.connect("http://" + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

socket.on("connect", function() {
    socket.send("Connected Socket off to get data");
});

socket.on("message", function (data) {
    chartConfig.data.datasets[0].data = data.result;
    let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    let myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, chartConfig)
});
```

Comment: In which moment you got the error? Could you add full trace to the question? How do you run `Flask` application and `Celery` application?

Comment: I run the Celery app using `python main.py`

Comment: I suspect that `send()` must be inside the socketio decorated function `handle_connection`. You could try using `send` in a callback to the `async_data` task. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks

Comment: Also check out this flask decorator [copy_current_request_context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.copy_current_request_context)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is only in the Flask. Let's made a little test(`main.py`):

```
from random import sample
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from celery_config import make_celery

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "thisisasecret"

app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL="redis://localhost:6379/0", # or your broker
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND="redis://localhost:6379/0" # or your broker
)
celery = make_celery(app)

@celery.task(name="main.async_data")
def async_data():
    jsonify({"result": sample(range(101), 6)})
    return True

@app.route("/")
def index():
    async_data.delay()
    return 'test'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Run Celery and Flask apps, open '/' route. You will see the next error:

> RuntimeError: Working outside of request context

How it works. You using [jsonify](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.json.jsonify) method. As you can see in the docs, it turns the JSON output into a Response object with the application/json mimetype. But `Celery task` doesn't know anything about current/active response of Flask. This is just asynchronous code/processing. If you need to work with json in celery you can use any lib(json, ujson, simplejson etc).

Now let's change `jsonify` to `json.dumps({"result": sample(range(101), 6)})`. You will see that everything works fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, it helps a bit. This issue is when using socketio. As I want the result of the `async_data()` to be emitted to the client

Comment: @Warmley the issue is not with socketio, js or something else. If you need to get result from `Celery task` you should use [AsyncResult](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult). You can get uuid of task when task was started and after that check status from the client side.

Comment: But then won't my client side be polling? Isn't the point of the websocket to long poll?

Comment: @Warmley Sorry, but I think your current questions are not related to this post. The problem which you described in the question was associated only with using Flask-Celery. If you have a new questions you can ask them and describe details. At the moment, comments have nothing to do with the question(trace, title etc.). Nothing personal, but it looks like questions within a question )))